# Replace value of object param with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, object, greasemonkey, parameters

Hello :)
I trying to manipulate with some object with Greasemoneky so i have to write a script :)
I want to change one value of allowFullScreen param.

```
<object width="760" height="660" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="flashc" name="flashc" data="http://example.com/swf/39.swf">
  <param name="menu" value="false">
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"> // I want to change this to **"true"**
  <param name="scale" value="noscale">
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"> 
</object>
```

I already written something but it doesn't work:

```
function allowFS()
{ 
    var obj = getElementsByName("allowFullScreen")
    obj.setAttribute("value", "true");

}
```

Sorry for my language

Answer (score 1):

Don't known of any `getElementsByName` function. Maybe it's a GreaseMonkey function. But in JS I would do something like:

```
var params = document.getElementsByTagName('param');

for ( var i = 0; i < params.length; i++ )
{
    if ( params[i].name == 'allowFullScreen' )
    {
        params[i].setAttribute('value', 'true');
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Sorry about my ignorance, `getElementsByName` exists and return and array-like as `getElementsByTagName`. So the code will be:

```
var params = document.getElementsByName('allowFullScreen');

for ( var i = 0; i < params.length; i++ )
{
    params[i].setAttribute('value', 'true');
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByName` exists and is supported by all major browser, so says w3schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work - all time i have "false" value :| But thanks anyway for trying to help :)

Comment: My code had a typo error. Now it's fixed. If `setAttribute` doesn't work, try `params[i].value = 'true'` directly.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName is a member of document and returns an array(I should better say "an array-like DOMNodeList").

So you should use:

```
var obj = document.getElementsByName("allowFullScreen")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not enough to alter the `allowFullScreen` value, because the flash object will have already been initialized with the old value.

To get around this, create a new flash object using the new `allowFullScreen` value from the start.

The following code should work, but it requires jQuery, so:

(1) Add this line to the Greasemonkey metadata section, just after the `// @include` directive(s):

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
```

(2) Using GM's "Manage User Scripts" panel, Uninstall and then reinstall the Greasemonkey script to ensure that the jQuery file is copied to your PC.

(3) Then try this code:

```
$('#flashc param[name="allowFullScreen"]').val ("true");
var jNewFlash = $('#flashc').clone (true);
$('#flashc').replaceWith (jNewFlash)
```

(Assumes that the `object` id is `flashc` as shown in the question.)

Comment: maybe i can't run scripts on GM :( [i doesn't work too ;/) But thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @Lyczos: Anyone can run GM scripts.  You need to specify exactly **how** it doesn't work.  It would also be best to post a link to the page you are trying to modify.